# Track Software Download from Website Email Address

Tags: wordpress, installation, analytics, event-tracking

I have a software package where a user gains access to the download link through email after they've submitted their email address.

So currently, it goes like this:

1. User goes to website and clicks "download"
2. Taken to page to enter in name/email and submit
3. User gets an email with the download link
4. The email link takes them to a non-indexed page where a script automatically starts the download after 5 seconds of being on that page.

We have Google Analytics installed on website and can currently track sources/campaigns to submitting for download but nothing beyond this.

We would like to be able to associate the download and install with the email address that the user submitted in step 2 above from the website.

Open to restructuring the process flow to accomplish tracking as long as they have to submit their email address before gaining access to download.

Website is using wordpress. Software is .exe app written with MS Visual Studio in C#.

Thanks in Advance,

Dustin

Comment: This violates the GA Terms of Service - you aren't supposed to store email addresses in the reports.

Comment: We aren't storing the email address in GA. It's stored in an email forum after submission, up to this point.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add token to url parameters that is unique and assigned to that email-address, so you can track it this way.

Comment: We're going to go with this method. That is, creating some sort of script to generate a unique download link with a tag name. Ex: The website visitor clicks to download via web form. Eaither in the email or upon the webpage provided with download link in the email will generate a unique ID. Let's call it "1". The download link will be "download-1.exe". During installation, the app will read the install file name and write this to a file in the application so that once it's successfully installed we can send this information elsewhere. No sure how to do this script but will update with solution